# Looking to create a team generator based on names in a list- Python

Tags: python, list

So I've been told to create two seperate football teams based on players.
What I have at the moment is the list of player names
and two seperate lists called team_1 and team_2
I am looking to randomly selected a player from this list and add it to team one or team two.
The code at the moment adds the player to the list in team one but I need it to remove the player that
has been added to team one from the player list so it can't be selected again.
I was planning on checking the length of the list to see if it was empty and if so then to stop the loop.
Does that make sense?

```
import random
team_1 = []
team_2 = []
players = ["john","garrett","aaron","mitchell"]
lenghth = len(players)
selected_team_one = random.choice(players)
team_1.append(selected_team_one)
selected_team_two = random.choice(players)
team_2.append(selected_team_two)
print(team_1)
print(team_2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `pop` method of list. It returns the last element and remove it, and if you gave it an index it returns the item in the index place and remove it from the list. You can get random index, `random. Randrange (len (players))`. I make it a function. Also the parameter, it a list and it by reference, that why it updates the original list (Python doesn't copy list (only if you tell it to do so))

```
import random

def get_random_player(players):
    return players.pop(random.randrange(len(players)))

team_1 = []
team_2 = []
players = ["john","garrett","aaron","mitchell"]

for x in range(len(players) // 2):
   team_1.append(get_random_player(players))
   team_2.append(get_random_player(players))

print(team_1)
print(team_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could select all the unique players you need for the first team with [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), then build the second one by taking all of the players that aren't in the first team:

```
import random

players = ["john","garrett","aaron","mitchell"]
length = len(players)
team_1 = random.sample(players, k=length//2)
team_2 = [player for player in players if player not in team_1]

print(team_1, team_2)
# ['aaron', 'john'] ['garrett', 'mitchell']
```

Comment: now I was hoping to announce who would be in each team by caling the teams out using a string like so 
```print("Team A will consist of" (*team_1))```
however this doesn't work, but this does
```print(*team_1)```
Any idea how I could join the two?

Comment: you need a comma. So: `print("Team A will consist of ", *team_1)`

Comment: you could also do like a dictionary and print off both: `team_dict = {'Team A': team_1, 'Team B': team_2}`

`for k,v in team_dict.items():
    print (k, ' will consist of ', *v)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'remove' to remove the selected player after you put him in a team:

```
$ players.remove(selected_team_one)
```

Exmaple :

```
import random
team_1 = []
team_2 = []
players = ["john","garrett","aaron","mitchell"]
length = len(players)
while players !=[]:
    selected_player = random.choice(players)
    team_1.append(selected_player)
    players.remove(selected_player)
    
    selected_player = random.choice(players)
    team_2.append(selected_player)
    players.remove(selected_player)

print(team_1)
print(team_2)
```

Comment: that works, i now have john and garett in two lists but I also want to remove them from the players list as well how would i do that?

Comment: This is already done in the script I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

### Using [random.shuffle()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

Let's say you have the player list:

```
players = [chr(element) for element in range(ord('A'), ord('Z'))]
#=> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', ...
```

And you want to build teams of five members each (need to check there are enough players):

```
team_members = 5
```

You can just shuffle the player list (maybe `copy()` it if you want to preserve the original) and pick the players using a [range(start, stop[, step])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range):

```
shuffle(players) # <- shuffle the list 
[players[x:x+team_members] for x in range(0, len(players), 5)]

#[['P', 'B', 'G', 'L', 'N'],
# ['R', 'C', 'E', 'S', 'X'],
# ['W', 'D', 'V', 'K', 'U'],
# ['T', 'A', 'O', 'I', 'Q'],
# ['H', 'Y', 'F', 'J', 'M']]
```

---

**Tip:** You can also group players by role in a `dict` and do the same building easily teams by role.